# Recommended way to overwrite built-in function (org-bbdb-format-vevent)

Tags: org-export

I'm using the icalendar export built into org-mode to export my agenda to an ical file. I also use org-bbdb to insert birthdays (anniversaries) into the agenda. Using the variable `org-icalendar-include-bbdb-anniversaries`,  these anniversaries are exported to the ical file, which is great.

The problem is that the format of these birthday entries is not customizable. I traced back the formatting of the org-bbdb entries to the ical entries to the function `org-bbdb-format-vevent`, defined in `org-bbdb.el`. Can I overwrite or modify this function without patching `org-bbdb.el`? If so, what's the recommended way to do that?

Comment: For rewriting a function, it is generally sufficient to `require` the library that contains the original function and then (below that `require` statement) you can have a new function *with the same function name as the old one* that does whatever you want.  You could also create a new function and then use `defalias` -- the same procedure regarding having a `require` statement beforehand is generally used.  And you could also use `advice` as BrianZ suggested in his answer below -- if the feature can be corrected by adding something before or after the original function, but not in-between.

Comment: See **Preferred method of overriding an emacs lisp function?**:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/15725437/2112489

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the formatting in bbdb specifically, but it sounds like you are looking to "advise" `org-bbdb-format-vevent`. Check out the manual which has [a section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html) on this topic.